# Как получить имя объекта в java?

Tags: java, классы, объекты

Доброго времени суток! Я написал простой код:

```
 package SelfBook_made.Other.Etudy;
 import java.lang.Math;  
 public class Wheel {
 double r;

Wheel(double r){
    this.r = r;  //инициализация колеса из конструктора
}
public double length1(){
    return 2*(Math.PI)*r;   //возврат длины окружности 
}

public double square_wheel(){
   return Math.PI*r*r;        //возврат площади окружности
}

void c(){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Длина колеса = " +length1());
    System.out.println("Площадь колеса = " +square_wheel() );
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Wheel w1 = new Wheel(5);  //Первое колесо
    Wheel w2 = new Wheel (3); // Второе колесо
    w1.c(); 
    w2.c();
  }
 }
```

На выходе программа даёт площадь и длину окружности колеса.
Как написать метод, чтобы моя программа возвращала имя колеса? 
Чтобы на выходе было:

- Колесо w1:
- Длина колеса = ...
- Площадь колеса = ...

Comment: Я по чесноку пробовал   методы вроде   public void name(Object evt) {
        System.out.println("Имя колеса: "+evt);
    } и всякие штуки вроде getName. И вопрос гуглил. Не нашел.

Comment: Добавляйте в класс наряду с радиусом еще и имя, и задавайте его в конструкторе как this.name = name; Ну а потом вывод указывайте как System.out.println("Колесо "+name);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По идее, правильным решением будет в классе Wheel создать переменную `string name` и инициализировать ее через конструктор. 
Т.к. из самого объекта Вы не можете узнать (без костылей), какая переменная на него ссылается.

```
package SelfBook_made.Other.Etudy;
import java.lang.Math;  
public class Wheel {
    double r;
    String name;

    Wheel(String name, double r){
        this.name = name;
        this.r = r;  //инициализация колеса из конструктора
    }

    public double length1(){
        return 2*(Math.PI)*r;   //возврат длины окружности 
    }

    public double square_wheel(){
        return Math.PI*r*r;        //возврат площади окружности
    }

    void c(){
        System.out.println("Колесо " + name + ":");
        System.out.println("Длина колеса = " +length1());
        System.out.println("Площадь колеса = " +square_wheel() );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wheel w1 = new Wheel("Колесо1", 5);  //Первое колесо
        Wheel w2 = new Wheel("Колесо2", 3); // Второе колесо
        w1.c(); 
        w2.c();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну спасибо. Будем что w1 без дополнительного поля, похоже никак не получить. Я скромно вам отвечу +1.

Comment: Даже если найти способ получить имя переменной из объекта, то это будет не корректно. Представьте, если, допустим, сделать так:

    `Wheel w1 = new Wheel("Колесо1", 5);
    Wheel w11 = w1;
    w1.c();
    w11.c();`

Неужели по Вашему мнению вывод в консоль должен быть разным? Объект то один и тот же, мы не создаем второе колесо. Мы всего лишь создаем вторую переменную, которая указывает на то же самое колесо.

Comment: а я где-то слышал, что у ∀ объекта должно быть уникальное имя. И даже если я склонирую объект, метод w1.equals.(w11) даст на выходе false.

Comment: Во-первых, уникальное имя и имя переменной - разные вещи. Во-вторых, присвоить значение переменной и склонировать объект - это тоже разные вещи.

Answer (score 3):

Имена локальных переменных не существуют. Надо передавать строку в метод и выводить её. Ну либо дабавить колесу свойство с именем и выводить его.

```
void c(String name){
    System.out.println("Колесо " + name + ":");
    System.out.println("Длина колеса = " + length1());
    System.out.println("Площадь колеса = " + square_wheel());
}

w1.c("w1");
w2.c("w2");
```

Comment: Да ну! Я так тоже делал. Какой-то код (имхо) с запашком.  Мне не понравилось. Ну всё равно плюсую.